# Java META-INF not working

Tags: java, executable-jar, manifest.mf

My jar file is not working at all. It isn't the class files that are messed up, but the meta-inf file. My main class is called Main.class. This is what my META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: .
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

try removing the `Class-Path:` line

Comment: Please click the tick below my votes to mark the answer as correct